# Create Interactive Scheduled Task with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am struggling to create a task which will run interactivly at logon.  This is the code I have:

```
$Action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'
$Trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn -User "[machine]\[user]"
$Principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -RunLevel Highest -UserId "[machine]\[user]" -LogonType Interactive
$Settings = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet -Priority 4
$Task = New-ScheduledTask -Action $Action -Trigger $Trigger -Principal $Principal -Settings $Settings
Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'InteractiveScript' -InputObject $Task -User "[machine]\[user]" -Password '[password]'
```

This does not set the task to run interactively as shown when I look at the GUI:

[image]

Getting the task via PowerShell:

```
$createdTask = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName 'InteractiveScript'
$createdTask.Principal.LogonType
```

Returns Password

What am I missing?

Comment: Remove `-User "[machine]\[user]" -Password '[password]'` from the call to `Register-ScheduledTask`

Comment: Thank you that did the trick!

Comment: Please consider writing an answer that could be marked as the solution.